# Doxygen parse const member function incorrectly when const at another line

Tags: c++, coding-style, doxygen

I've tried searching stackoverflow and [users mailing list](http://sourceforge.net/mail/?group_id=5971) in the official website but not found something useful to my problem, there are a lot of results unrelated...

Doxygen I used is version 1.8.5.

I prefer to style my member function declaration like this, let's call it
const-at-another-line style.

```
ReturnType
FunctionName()
const;
```

I know most people just use all-in-same-line style,

```
ReturnType FunctionName() const;
```

or just return-type-at-another-line style

```
ReturnType
FunctionName() const;
```

for both all-in-same-line style and return-type-at-another-line style, doxygen
can parse correctly.

However the document of const-at-another-line style results in a Member Data
called "const" and type is ReturnType.

```
class Signal : public Interface {
    bool
    HasSignal()
    const;
};
```

document shows class `Signal` has Public Attributes

```
bool const
```

and detailed documentation in Member Data Documentations shows

```
bool Signal::const
```

I've also tried these cases, pure virtual function:

```
bool
HasSignal()
const =0;
```

result in

```
bool Signal::const =0
```

and C++11 final/override keyword:
(I'm not expecting Doxygen fully support C++11 syntax yet, just for comparison)

```
bool
HasSignal()
const
override;
```

results in Public Attributes

```
bool const override
```

which "const" link to Member Data Documentation in class `Interface`

```
virtual bool Interface::const = 0
```

and "override" link to Member Data Documentation in class `Signal`

```
bool const Signal::override
```

My problem is:
Is there some config in Doxygen I missed that can help to parse/document
const member function using const-at-another-line style correctly?
Or I can only modify style to fit Doxygen for document purpose?

Comment: Looks like this has been fixed in version 1.8.6 and later (note that version 1.8.5 was released in August 2013 so it is rather old).

Comment: I will check with new version, thanks!

Comment: @doxygen I have downloaded version 1.8.6 and confirmed that it has been fixed in 1.8.6, I also searched changelog but not sure which item document this change. Can you reply again instead of comment so I can accept it as answer? Thanks for this great tool!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this has been fixed in version 1.8.6 and later (note that version 1.8.5 was released in August 2013 so it is rather old). Latest version as of writing is 1.8.9.1.